# Concatinating text files with MPI

Tags: c, mpi

Is there an easy way to concatenate several text files coming from multiple cores on a single core.

Core 0

```
1 4 6 4 2 6
4 5 4 2 4 7
3 5 6 7 8 5
```

Core 1

```
5 6 7 5 3 6
5 6 7 8 5 4
6 4 3 5 6 7
```

Core 2

```
6 7 8 5 3 6
4 5 7 3 4 5
8 7 6 5 2 3
6 7 8 6 5 4
8 9 0 3 2 1
```

I want to add the text files on core 0 with the text files from core 1 and core 2.  I know it's something like...

```
int textSize = ...; // size of text file on each core 
      if (rank == 0) {
            int size = malloc(sizeof(float) * textSize);
      }
      MPI_Gather(&name_of_text_file, textSize, MPI_FLOAT, *size, textSize, MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I understand you don't want to concatenate files (e.g. write on the disk) but rather gather all the local arrays to one. I also guess that you want to use numbers (what kind?) and not text. Are these right?

Comment: Yeah,  they are all floats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you are not refering to text files, but to arithmetic data, accessed through pointers. I also understand that your problem is that not all the processes have the same size of data.

In this case, probably you are looking for the [*MPI_Gather**v***](http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/latest/www3/MPI_Gatherv.html) function. It works pretty much like the MPI_Gather function, but you can define for each process how many data will be sent (the `recvcounts` array, specified at the receiving rank) and were they will be put in the target location (the `displs` array).

Here are two examples from the documentation of the [MPI Forum](http://mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-1.1/mpi-11-html/node70.html):

**Simple MPI_Gather**, in which only the master rank allocates the memory for the complete array of data:

```
MPI_Comm comm; 
int gsize,sendarray[100]; 
int root, myrank, *rbuf; 
... 
MPI_Comm_rank( comm, myrank); 
if ( myrank == root) { 
   MPI_Comm_size( comm, &gsize); 
   rbuf = (int *)malloc(gsize*100*sizeof(int)); 
   } 
MPI_Gather( sendarray, 100, MPI_INT, rbuf, 100, MPI_INT, root, comm);
```

[image: Example of MPI_Gather (from MPI Forum)]

In this example, all the processes have chunks of 100 integers. In your case you may want to change `int` to `float`.

**MPI_Gatherv**:

```
MPI_Comm comm; 
    int gsize,sendarray[100]; 
    int root, *rbuf, stride; 
    int *displs,i,*rcounts; 
...      
MPI_Comm_size( comm, &gsize); 
    rbuf = (int *)malloc(gsize*stride*sizeof(int)); 
    displs = (int *)malloc(gsize*sizeof(int)); 
    rcounts = (int *)malloc(gsize*sizeof(int)); 
    for (i=0; i<gsize; ++i) { 
        displs[i] = i*stride; 
        rcounts[i] = 100; 
    } 
    MPI_Gatherv( sendarray, 100, MPI_INT, rbuf, rcounts, displs, MPI_INT, 
                                                               root, comm);
```

[image: Example of MPI_Gatherv (from MPI Forum)]

In this example, the same number of elements are received (100 integers) and put regularly in memory areas that are separated by `stride` integers. The target array (`rbuf`) can store (*number_of_ranks* * *stride*) integers.

You can perfectly ignore the fixed-size *stride* and set the `displs` and `rcounts` individually for each process, if you know them. If you don't know them, look at the last example in the MPI Forum page.

*In any case, I assume that you are using single pointers for your data* (e.g. array[i]) and not double (e.g. array[i][j]). This requires some extra effort to set the correct indices, but is simpler to use in MPI and in some cases also faster.